# Python regex '\s' does not match unicode BOM (U+FEFF)

Tags: python, regex, unicode

The Python `re` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) says that when the `re.UNICODE` flag is set, `'\s'` will match:

> whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.

As far I can tell, the BOM (U+FEFF) is [classified as a space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#Whitespace).

However:

```
re.match(u'\s', u'\ufeff', re.UNICODE)
```

evaluates to `None`.

Is this a bug in Python or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

U+FEFF is not a whitespace character according to the unicode database.

Wikipedia only lists it as it is a "related character". These are similar to whitespace characters but don't have the `WSpace` property in the database.

None of those characters are matched by `\s`.

Comment: `len([c for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode + 1)) if unicodedata.category(c) == 'Cf' and c.isspace()])` is zero.